# Autocad 2011 vba and xrefs

Tags: vba, autocad

I am inserting an external dwg file in another one using this:

```
Set xrefInserted = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AttachExternalReference(refDwgName, refDwgName, insertionPnt, 1, 1, 1, 0, False)
xrefInserted.Update
```

This is inserted as a external block, so I bind it to my drawing:

```
        For Each tempBlock In ThisDrawing.Blocks
           If tempBlock.IsXRef Then
               If (InStr(1, UCase(tempBlock.name), "MAJ_MATRICE", vbTextCompare)) Then
                    tempBlock.Bind (False)
                   Exit For
               End If
            End If
        Next
```

Now I want to explode it, first thing AcadBlock does not seem to have and explode method, only AcadBlockReference.

So I look for the reference:

```
Dim ent As AcadEntity
Dim blockRefObj As AcadBlockReference

    For Each ent In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
       If TypeOf ent Is AcadBlockReference Then
           If (InStr(1, UCase(ent.name), "MAJ_MATRICE", vbTextCompare)) Then
                Set blockRefObj = ent
                blockRefObj.Explode
                Exit For
           End If
       End If
    Next
```

The problem, is

> blockRefObj.Explode

fails it tells me "Not valid -2145386494".

I debugged the code and I beleive the problem is because the AcadBlockReference is still of type AcadExternalReference and it is not possible to explode a external reference.

If I rerun the code after I am taken back to the drawing (the function call has ended) and I look for the AcadBlockReference, it is now of type AcadBlockReference and I can correctly explode it.

I just can't seem to be able to do it in the same function, in the same execution as binding it.

Comment: Where are the Dim statements for **blockRefObj** and **ent**?

Comment: Did you tried with Bind(True)? (just to debug)

Comment: Hello, I just tried, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see why you wouldn't start off by using thisdrawing.modelspace.insertblock ? 
This returns an acadblockreference object in the first place !